# Creating Aurora Cluster with Postgresql with CDK

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, aws-cdk

Running CDK with db-stack that contains:

```
    this.cluster = new DatabaseCluster(this, 'ProductDatabase', {
      defaultDatabaseName: 'ProductDb',
      engine: DatabaseClusterEngine.AURORA_POSTGRESQL,
      engineVersion: '11.4',
      masterUser: {
        username: 'clusteradmin',
      },
      instanceProps: {
        instanceType: InstanceType.of(InstanceClass.BURSTABLE2, InstanceSize.SMALL),
        vpcSubnets: {
          subnetType: SubnetType.ISOLATED,
        },
        vpc: props.vpc,
      },
      parameterGroup: ParameterGroup.fromParameterGroupName(this, 'ParameterGroup', 'default.aurora-postgresql11'),
    })
```

fails with error message:

```
RDS does not support creating a DB instance with the following combination: DBInstanceClass=db.t2.small, Engine=aurora-postgresql, EngineVersion=11.4, LicenseModel=postgresql-license. For supported combinations of instance class and database engine version, see the documentation. (Service: AmazonRDS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterCombination; Request ID: dfb07895-5687-486e-a39e-49b0e59a170f)
```

From what I can find from AWS documentation, 11.4 is supported and `db.t2.small` is allowed for all Postgreqsql versions. Also commandline `aws rds  describe-db-engine-versions --engine=aurora-postgresql` does include:

```
       {
            "Engine": "aurora-postgresql",
            "EngineVersion": "11.4",
            "DBParameterGroupFamily": "aurora-postgresql11",
            "DBEngineDescription": "Aurora (PostgreSQL)",
            "DBEngineVersionDescription": "Aurora PostgreSQL (Compatible with PostgreSQL 11.4)",
            "ValidUpgradeTarget": [],
            "ExportableLogTypes": [
                "postgresql"
            ],
            "SupportsLogExportsToCloudwatchLogs": true,
            "SupportsReadReplica": false,
            "SupportedEngineModes": [
                "provisioned"
            ],
            "SupportedFeatureNames": [
                "s3Import"
            ],
            "Status": "available"
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/Concepts.DBInstanceClass.html), from t-type (burstable) instances, Aurora Postgresql supports only `t3.medium`. So this line fixes the definition:

```
instanceType: InstanceType.of(InstanceClass.BURSTABLE3, InstanceSize.MEDIUM),
```